# How to change settings for C++ project locally?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I would like to change settings (using Visual Studio 2012) that go to `.vcxproj.user` (not `.vcxproj`), because I would like to keep them locally and not commit to repo.

I was under impression that going "project --> properties" let me edit global settings, while going "View -> Property Manager -> Project -> Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User --> Properties" allow me to edit my own, user, settings.

Yet, changes from both edits ended up in ".vcxproj" file.

---

Here is what MS have to say: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx You may notice that some things do not add up -- they say there are user settings which are kept system-wide in project directory. This is a contradiction.

There is no info how to edit .vcxproj.user except for suggestion the best practice is to delete the file.

So I created a property sheet, locally (per project) instead of editing .vcxproj.user. I can edit it as expected, but the problem is, .vxproj keeps track of it, which means that I have to commit my user settings in repo, because otherwise project will fail to load (missing property sheet). But having user file which has to be committed beats its purpose.

So far I am stuck.

Comment: Check if the debug settings are saved to `vcxproj.user`, if it is then probably, just by convention `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User` settings are going to `vcxproj`

Comment: @deimus, Currently I edit debug settings, as I wrote, both edits went to global .vcxproj file. So my question is how to edit .vcxproj.user (of course not with notepad ;-) ).

Comment: Probably your current project has corrupted settings somehow, start a new blank project, change the debug settings and check if it goes to `vcxproj.user`.

Comment: @deimus, I did, I entered unique values, and from what I see the first path (see my question) alters .vcxproj file, while the second alters system wide settings (?). However none of the edits changed .vcxproj.user file.

Comment: Thats pretty much strange, I would suggest you to open `vcxproj.user` manually (yes with notepad or whatever..) change some values and try spot how do they reflect on a new session of a VS12

Comment: @deimus, thank you. After rereading for N-th time info from MS I think they screwed sth up. So I gave up and created my own properties sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! The solution is to create property sheets (plural) each per Debug/Release. I notice that creating common property sheet is possible, but some of the settings are then ignored -- not useful.

After that you close the project and edit .vcxproj manually. Look for your property sheets entries, and add `Condition` on `exists` -- this will check of the file exists.

This will allow to load solution without any error if property sheets are not present -- typical case when somebody read the project from the repo.